# Search by conversation, not all emails flagged as done

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2016

Is there a way to create a search folder in Outlook, that returns conversations where not all emails in the thread/conversation have been flagged as completed/done?

Possibly to search by the email conversation header?

The search should omit conversations where all emails are flagged as completed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Application.AdvancedSearch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/bb219884(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) method which performs a search based on a specified DAV Searching and Locating (DASL) search string. Admittedly, the `Search` class allows you to save the results of searching in a search folder (actually, it doesn’t contain any items, only references to items from the scope folders). You just need to call the `Save` method on the `Search` object in the `AdvanvedSearchComplete` event handler to create a search folder with results.

To get the conversation items you can use the [GetConversation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.getconversation) method which obtains a `Conversation` object that represents the conversation to which this item belongs. So, you may find all items that were not flagged/done and then process each item by getting the conversation it belongs to.

Finally, to find the required search criteria you may take a look at the [Filtering Items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/bb147579(v=office.12)) article. For example, you may consider using the [MailItem.IsMarkedAsTask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.ismarkedastask) and [MailItem.TaskCompletedDate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.taskcompleteddate) properties in your query.